# Почему ??????? вместо слов

Tags: база-данных, php, ajax

Здравствуйте ХешКод, вот решил сделать чат на Ajax, всё сделал как в уроке, но беда в том что когда я отправляю сообщение вместо **русских** слов в базу вставляется ?????????, таблица указана utf8_general_ci... вот урок откуда я писал всё это:

- [Первый урок](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o91CVJZgLvA&feature=relmfu)
- [Второй урок](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6Ve4HKNDOk&feature=relmfu)
- [Третий урок](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmE5sk_8N-g&feature=channel&list=UL)
- [Четвертый урок](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pmQ7KR8HCM0&feature=channel&list=UL)
- [Пятый урок](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ScM9acC0vQw&feature=channel&list=UL)

Просто я уже не знаю почему это всё не работает ;(

Comment: В какой кодировке база?

В какой кодировке сайт?

В какой кодировке файлы PHP?

В какой кодировке файлы JS?

После ответа на эти вопросы можно будет думать..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С кодировкой косяк, перед вставкой обрабытывайте переменную функцией 
`$perem = iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1251', $perem);`
Ну или наоборот, смотря какая кодировка.

Comment: А как определить в какой кодировке текст добавляется в базу? Просто я не знаю КАКУЮ кодировку заменить на urf-8...

Comment: Попробовать 2 варианта:
$perem = iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1251', $perem);
$perem = iconv('windows-1251', 'utf-8', $perem); и посмотреть какой разботает.

Comment: Не работают оба варианта :(

Comment: Хорошо, если сдеать $perem = iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1251', $perem); и далее распечатать значение $perem, перед вставкой в БД.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте перед самим запросом:
    `mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');`

Comment: У меня проблема возникает при добавлении записи, а не при выводе.

Comment: Это происходит потому что кодировка данных получаемых через ajax utf-8.

Answer (score 2):

После соединения с базой данных я обычно вставляю это:

```
   mysql_set_charset("utf8");
    mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
    mysql_query ("set character_set_client='utf8'");
    mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");
    mysql_query ("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
    mysql_query("set names 'utf-8'");
    setlocale (LC_CTYPE, "ru_RU.UTF-8");
```

Comment: @Эмиль Сабитов, если бы Вы знали, сколько это на самом деле запросов. Уж iconv() использовать проще.

Comment: Да, почему-то я не задумывался об этом. Просто тут мне ответили вставлять я так и начал.
Сейчас озадачили прям. Спасибо, буду исправляться.
Можно ли как-нибудь узнавать на сколько загружает систему,  какой-либо скрипт?

Comment: @Эмиль Сабитов, http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/05/13/how-to-calculate-cpu-usage-of-a-php-script/